# Does a Vue "Ref" lose its reactivity when reassigned a new instance of an object?

Tags: vuejs3

Initially, the property is initialized like this;

```
.....
setup(){
    let a = ref(new o());
    .......
}
........
```

then later, the variable `a` is reassigned like this;

```
const resetA = () => {
    a.value = new o()
}
```

Once the above function is executed, the variable `a` loses its reactivity. Is that normal?

**Update**

Once I reassign `a` as shown above, the properties of `a` lose their reactivity. Assume class `o` looks like this;

```
class o{
    j;
    k;
    l;
    public constructor() {
        j = '';
        k = '';
        l = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that shouldn't happen. Can you provide a *runnable* [mcve]? Most likely, it's something else, not present in the above code, where you're re-assigning `a` altogether, not only its value. To find out where, simply change `let` to `const` and your IDE should warn about assigning to a `const` wherever that happens.

Comment: Currently the question is unanswerable for lack of reproducing and debugging details.

Comment: The updated question still doesn't reproduce the issue.  see this [demo](https://shorturl.at/foJP2) of your code working as expected.  Provide a demo yourself if you can reproducing the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the comments; the components I am working with are a little complicated. I can see that the reactivity should work as expected based on your comments. I will debug the whole thing again.